# Opening the activity on top of another like Popup with some part visible of first activity

Tags: android, sdk, dialog, popup

I have an application in which my requirement is to show Home screen and then if any button is clicked open another activity in Popup(Which means remaining part of first activity will be visible but not click-able) and if any button is clicked in the second activity launch the third activity same as second.

Also I am not looking for setting in manifest: **@android:style/Theme.Dialog**[image]

In the image you can see a pop up and a parent screen behind that popup.Please help me to solve this. I have to open an activity on top of another activity with some part of previous visible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the theme of the first activity to dialog and it will look like this .... add this in <activity tag in manifest

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >

Comment: If you set a transparent background on your second activity, the previous activity will be visible underneath it. Then just scale the content.

Comment: Hi Squeazer Can you please tell me how to make background transparent in the second activity because I have tried setting that but only I can see is a white background in the rest part of the screen and previous background is not visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set the style of an activity to open it as pop up using:- **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"** in Manifest for activity you want to open as Popup and providing margins to layout.

Answer (score 3):

just add this tag to your activity tag in your manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

then the activity will look according to your requirements hope this helps ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use AlertDialog and inflate its custom layout in its setView() method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog
// layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null));
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
ad.setTitle("Your title");
ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
});
ad.show();
```